# Flash object doesn't fit the size when the browser zoomed

Tags: flash, embed, scale

I'm using flex. The flash object is remain the same size and not scaling when zoom in/out from browser. So the swf is not properly displayed in the given div. I'm wondering how [this example](http://elventales.com/durians-revenge/) could scaling nicely when zoomed in/out. Any solution besides adding the code to ActionScript is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution..

Just add `preinitialize="systemManager.stage.scaleMode = 'showAll'"` at the top of flex code inside `<s:Application>` (it's where we define xmlns: blablabla).

That should make it. When we zoom the browser, the flash object scaling nicely.

Comment: You don't have stage when preinitialize only after added to stage.

Answer (score 0):

Add this actionsctip code:
`stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;`
There is no another way.

Comment: Thanks Emin..I've tried it, but it shows some error. Looks like we have to add more code or modify it than just adding stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL; in the middle of AS code.